# Windows 2k8 ISO's download as zips

Tags: windows, iso-image

Does anyone know why this does that? I've downloaded the Windows 2k8 Enterprise ISO directly from the Microsoft website on my Windows 2k8 Stanard R2 VPS and it's going as a zip but with the extension .iso. So whenever I install it, I get an error that a certain file is missing or corrupt.

Comment: Uhm, what?  Point us at the URL.  Why do you think it is a 'ZIP'  Are you confusing the fact that your zip compression program can open an ISO file with the idea that is a zip file?  Just because 7zip and other tools can open a iso, doesn't mean that an iso is a zip.

Comment: http://puu.sh/3ReEu.png

Comment: That's an ISO file. You just have your .iso extension associated with WinRAR. Just because the file association is different, doesn't change the actual contents of the file. It's still an ISO file - if you want it changed, change your file association on your workstation. So, let's get to your actual problem - what is the exact error message you get when trying to use the ISO file?

Comment: It was some WMI or WIM error saying there was something from /Source that is missing or corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a new copy of the ISO to rule out any corruption with the ISO?

Comment: ISO disk images *are* archives. Any decent compression program can unpack them. They're more analogous to a .tar than a .zip though.

Comment: I went ahead and installed Windows Server 2008 R2 instead, and it worked perfectly. Thanks! :)